# Modal Popup Extender not working from logged in event

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

After user sucessfully logs in I am trying to ask users which page they want to view.

I have tried this with modal popup extender, but Modal popup extender does not show when I try to call it from loggedin event. Code is listed below. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        user_redirection_process();

        switch (validateResult)
        {
            case "M":
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

                break;
            case "A":                    
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/A/A.aspx");
                break;
            case "B":
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/B/B.aspx");
                break;
            default:
                //Response.Redirect("~/Account/A/A.aspx");
                break;

        }

    }
```

I am using membership framework and login control to handle login process.

Front End looks like this:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style ="display:none">
    <a href="Account/A/A.aspx">dkny</a>
    <a href="Account/B/B.aspx">dko</a>

</asp:Panel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="dummy" runat="server" style="display:none">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" DropShadow="True" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="dummy"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: have you specified TargeControl in while initializing it ? something like :<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlMSG" CancelControlID="btnSubscribe"
     TargetControlID="HiddenField1">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

Comment: yes, i have. i have updated the question with codes used  in frontend

Comment: What gbs has mentioned below is correct still to verify after click the button to show modal pop up you can open console to see it any error has been tracked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Login Control upon successful login, you will be automatically redirected to the DefaultUrl or RedirectUrl supplied by FormsAuthentication.

So I believe, you will have to use regular inputs and button for login and handle the login mechanism accordingly.